# FATAL_ERROR|System.ListException: Row with null Id at index: 0

Tags: soql

I'm trying to query the Products that has more than 3 Quantity

Below is my query:

```
Set<Id> extras = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    SELECT Product2Id
    FROM OpportunityLineItem
    WHERE Product2Id In: oppIds
    GROUP BY Product2Id
    HAVING SUM(quantity) > 3
]).keySet();
```

Any ideas on why I'm having

> FATAL_ERROR|System.ListException: Row with null Id at index: 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using an AggregateResult query with the `Map<Id, AggregateResult>` constructor, you need to *alias* the field to the specific alias `Id` (case-sensitive):

```
Set<Id> extras = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    SELECT Product2Id Id
    FROM OpportunityLineItem
    WHERE Product2Id In: oppIds
    GROUP BY Product2Id
    HAVING SUM(quantity) > 3
]).keySet();
```

Comment: Such a big help! Thank you so much for the additional knowledge :)